# Getting distance between 2 geometries in mysql 5.5

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

Is there any way to use st_distance (5.6 mysql function) or similar, in a mysql 5.5 database?

Comment: You'll have to code it yourself using the Haversine formula. Google it.

Comment: With respect, your question is not clear. What's a "geometry?" A point? What sort of distance computation do you need?  Are these latitude and longitude? Or what? It's possible your question can be saved if you edit it to make it clearer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql spatial distance using POINT - Not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436396/mysql-spatial-distance-using-point-not-working)