# Find nearest points with MySQL from points Table

Tags: mysql, algorithm, geolocation, location, query-builder

I have a [DB Schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_(database)) like this (from [**this tutorial by Google**](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?csw=1#creating-the-table)) -

[image: DB Schema]

So the actual points in a graph for them is like this-

[image: Physical Location]

What I want is to find points near a given point (by **point_id**) point ordered by distance

> Location of a point `(x,y)` is (`point_x`,`point_y`) in DB

I want to solve it with [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/) because my DB is already in MySQL.

---

### Update-

Finding distance of 2 points is so easy like this-

[image: Finding distance]

I want to sort on distance with MySQL.

---

### Re-

For removing the confusions, I want the points inside the circle, later. But now I want to find only the sorted points.

So u can ignore the circles.

---

I don't have any idea how to do it, can anyone please help?

Comment: How would you define `nearest points`?

Comment: It is a common question to find distance between 2 points, it is given in updated question

Comment: I didn't ask for that. You marked a circle. Probably you want all those points inside the circle. That's why I asked what's your criteria to grab those points?

Comment: Yes, I want the points inside the circle, later.

But now I want to find only the sorted points

Comment: Question updated for your kind info.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have found a better solution than @1000111 's solution.

There is custom DB type in MySQL for this kind of data which gives a better performance.

[**OpenGIS** in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/opengis-geometry-model.html) is perfect for this.

Functions are given **[here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-linestring-property-functions.html)**.

An illustrative definition is given in **[this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995428/storing-lat-lng-values-in-mysql-using-spatial-point-type)**.

My solution is like this-

**DB Table**-

```
CREATE TABLE geoTable
(
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    geoPoint POINT NOT NULL,
    SPATIAL INDEX(geoPoint)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;


INSERT INTO geoTable (name, geoPoint)
VALUES
  ( "A", GeomFromText('POINT(0.1 -1.01)') ),
  ( "B", ST_GeomFromText('POINT(56.31 2.81)') ),
  ( "C", ST_GeomFromText('POINT(11.1 1.176)') ),
  ( "ui", ST_GeomFromText('POINT(9.1 2.1)') );
```

**SQL Query**-

```
SELECT
  id,
  name,
  X(geoPoint) AS "latitude",
  Y(geoPoint) AS "longitude",
  (
    GLength(
      LineStringFromWKB(
        LineString(
          geoPoint, 
          GeomFromText('POINT(51.5177 -0.0968)')
        )
      )
    )
  )
  AS distance
FROM geoTable
  ORDER BY distance ASC;
```

---

### An example SQL Fiddle is given [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84ad7/1/0).

See the execution time-

[image]

For 150 entry, it is only 13ms.

Comment: Why the `LineStringFromWKB` ? Without it, the query runs fine with exactly same result

Comment: If your table is very large, you might filter it using the `MBRContains` function, before sorting, as this can make use of SPATIAL indexes.

Comment: `LineStringFromWKB` Why use it? Can you please explain?

Comment: How about high dimensions?

Comment: ST_Distance( geoPoint , 'POINT(51.5177 -0.0968)' )          OR       
ST_Distance_Sphere( geoPoint , 'POINT(51.5177 -0.0968)' )

Answer (score 1):

Try this query please [a straight forward approach]:

Suppose, you want to find the nearest 20 points of the point having `point_id = 5`

`SET @givent_point_id := 5;`

```
SELECT 
P1.point_id,
P1.point_name,
P1.point_x,
P1.point_y,
(POW(ABS((P2.point_x - P1.point_x)),2) + POW(ABS((P2.point_y - P1.point_y)),2)) AS sqr_distance
FROM Point P1,
    (SELECT point_x,point_y FROM Point WHERE point_id = @givent_point_id) P2
WHERE P1.point_id <> @givent_point_id
ORDER BY sqr_distance
LIMIT 20;
```

[**Demo Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/913e69/1/1)

**More:** You may have a look at [**MySQL SPATIAL DATATYPE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-spatial-columns.html).

MySQL spatial indexes use `R-tree` as data structure which is specially designed for spatial access methods.

> R-trees are tree data structures used for spatial access methods,
>   i.e., for indexing multi-dimensional information such as geographical
>   coordinates, rectangles or polygons.

Comment: Sorry to say, I can't use this straight forward way.

Because it is too slow and if the total points> 10000 then we can't expect an answer from this query

Comment: Because it is server, so may be 1000 request comes in 1 sec and there may be 100000 points.

SO this procedure will fail

Comment: No, it is DB budy, so we have to apply some algo to find result in a efficient way, not this way

Comment: Have you run this query? What's the execution time? You may share the `Explain ...` result of this query. @AbrarJahin

Comment: There is only 4 points now, so u can't compare.

Can compare if u have `10000 points` or more.

NP, let me try if there is any alternative, if not, I should have accept your answer.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I have found a better and efficient way for it